# How to get last record for group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called tbl_chat and tbl_post.
The tbl_chat is given as follows.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  chat_id  |  message  |  from_user  |  to_user  |  post_id  |send_date         |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    1      |   Hi      |     23      |    A      |    35     |  2016-04-01 17:35|
|    2      |   Test    |     24      |    A      |    35     |  2016-04-02 01:35|
|    3      |   Thut    |      A      |   23      |    35     |  2016-04-02 03:35|
|    4      |   test    |      A      |   24      |    35     |  2016-04-02 12:35|
|    5      |   Hi      |     23      |    A      |    35     |  2016-04-03 17:35|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now, in the chat table we can see three users are interacting with each other. The Admin (A), user with id = 23 and user = 24.

So there is basically two chat thread.

1. One between A and 23
2. Another between A and 24.

I want a query which will show the two chat threads, with the last chat message. Just like in case of facebook chat list showing all the chat-threads with mentioning the last chat.

I am writing a query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_chat, tbl_post
WHERE tbl_post.post_id = tbl_chat.post_id
AND tbl_post.post_id = '39'
GROUP BY tbl_chat.chat_from
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The query has a problem. It is first retrieving all the chats and grouping it w.r.t. `chat_from` and then ORDERING it Descending-wise.

So first it's creating the group, and then ordering the group.

Also, the first query produces three group, taking the reply message from Admin as a separate group. Since GROUP BY chat_from.

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:-
I would be grateful if someone can build the query in **Active-Records of Codeigniter.**

Comment: what type is your `date`. seems you keep just `DATE` but not `DATETIME`?

Comment: First store dates using an appropriate date data type.

Comment: @Strawberry, Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(chat_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,message VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,from_user VARCHAR(12)
,to_user VARCHAR(12)
,post_id INT NOT NULL
,send_date DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Hi'  ,'23','A' ,35,'2016-04-01 17:35:00'),
(2,'Test','24','A' ,35,'2016-04-02 01:35:00'),
(3,'Thut','A' ,'23',35,'2016-04-02 03:35:00'),
(4,'test','A' ,'24',35,'2016-04-02 12:35:00'),
(5,'Hi'  ,'23','A' ,35,'2016-04-03 17:35:00');


SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT LEAST(from_user,to_user) user1
            , GREATEST(from_user,to_user) user2
            , MAX(send_date) send_date 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY user1
            , user2
     ) b
    ON b.user1 = LEAST(a.from_user,a.to_user)
   AND b.user2 = GREATEST(a.from_user,a.to_user)
   AND b.send_date = a.send_date;

+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
| chat_id | message | from_user | to_user | post_id | send_date           |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
|       4 | test    | A         | 24      |      35 | 2016-04-02 12:35:00 |
|       5 | Hi      | 23        | A       |      35 | 2016-04-03 17:35:00 |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Where are you seting post=35?

Comment: They're all 35, so I ignored that bit. I leave it as a challenge to the reader (albeit a very, very easy one)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_chat
INNER JOIN tbl_post
 ON tbl_post.post_id = tbl_chat.post_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_chat s
                 WHERE tbl_chat.from_user IN(s.from_user,s.to_user)
                   AND tbl_chat.to_user IN(s.from_user,s.to_user)
                   AND tbl_chat.date < s.date)
```

Although `date` field looks like `DATE` type, which is curious - how would you find the difference between two messages at the same day?

Comment: Sorry, that is date-time. Edited the question